# @Before doesn't execute in java Cucumber Step

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd

I've got a Cucumber Step class that i'm attempting to initialise a page model for all scenarios. So I added a @Before annotated method :

```
@Before()
private void beforeScenario() {
    LOGGER.info("Running before!");
    loginPage = BrowserDriver.getPageModel(LoginPage.class);
}
```

I've then got a bunch of steps that rely on loginPage being set. e.g.

```
@When("^I click the help link$")
public void I_click_the_help_link() {
    loginPage.clickHelpLink();
}
```

I have multiple Step classes.  Both of the methods above are in the same same Step class. 
However loginPage is always null. The beforeScenario method is never being called. Have I completely misunderstood how @Before is meant to work? Any tips on how to get what I want to work?

Edit : I also have an @After annotated method that does get run after every scenario as expected.

Edit : Pom can be seen at : http://pastebin.com/PJ6qQRK9

Comment: How do you know `beforeScenario` is never called. Have you tried with inserting a `println` there. Try and see if it is getting printed.

Comment: I know it's never called because I put breakpoints in there when running in my IDE and I never hit them. I also know because the LOGGER.info("Running after!") line in my @After annotated method shows in my logs while the expected log line for the beforeScenario is not written to the logs.

Comment: Check your cucumber.yml whether you have pasted the hooks path in that

Comment: It works for me with version `1.1.5 and 1.1.6`. Which version are you on?

Comment: @Bala : I was version 1.1.7, but downgrading to 1.1.5 doesn't help.

Comment: @NMKP : I don't have a cucumber.yml file, I presume that's something used by non java implementations of cucumber.

Comment: Could you show your `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

1. Make sure you are using `cucumber.annotation.Before` rather than `org.junit.Before`.  Cucumber will not process JUnit annotations.  (More information in the Scenario Hooks section of [this blog post](http://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/09/cucumber-jvm-hooks/).)
2. Make sure your @Before method is `public`, not `private`.

Comment: I got excited when I saw this post as it seemed a likely issue and an easy oversight. However I'm using the cucumber.api.java.Before annotation. I can't find cucumber.annotation.Before, I presume it was removed in later releases.

Comment: I've had a play about with some of my cucumber-jvm tests and I think I've spotted it.  Your `@Before` method should be `public` rather than `private`

Comment: Easy oversight number 2 has it. Thanks a ton, that's a great spot.

Comment: `import cucumber.api.java.Before;` is the correct import

Comment: Thank you! I had the exact same problem

Comment: cucumber.annotation.Before is not a correct location, but cucumber.api.java.Before is as of cucumber-java 7.2.3 , Apr,2022

Answer (score 19):

Hello I know that is an old post, but none of these solutions work for me. So I'm going to share my solution.

I created the class `Hooks` under the package: `com.mycompany.automation.util`

```
package com.mycompany.automation.util;

import com.mycompany.automation.rest.database.AS400DBManager;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * @author <a href="mesaj@mycompany.com">Julian Mesa</a>
 * @version 0.1.0
 * @since 0.1.0
 */

    public class Hooks {

      @After
      public void beforeScenario() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.print("Closing connection.");
        AS400DBManager.getInstance().closeConnection();
      }

    }
```

and then I specified the package in the glue options in the runner:

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources/features",
    glue = {"com.mycompany.automation.features.steps",
        "com.mycompany.automation.util"}
)
```

And it worked.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the answer ; to improve the answer, the trick lies in including package as  'glue' param.

Comment: This is where mostly people mistake. forget to mention package name in runner if hooks created in separate package. Nice answer. +1

Answer (score 6):

There is an accepted answer to this question, but I wanted to point out the comment made by Matt Watson which solved the issue for me and for which I have not seen similar advice elsewhere:

> I've had a play about with some of my cucumber-jvm tests and I think I've spotted it. Your `@Before` method should be `public` rather than `private`

The `@Before` method *must* be `public`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this Is an old issue but I found a Solution using the 5.5.0 version of cucumber java:
I added the Hooks class into the Steps package, having only the glue="Step classpath" and it worked fine for me :)

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 1):

**I know this issue is old, but in case somebody runs into the same problem using IntelliJ:**

Check the "Glue"-Property in your Run/Debug Configuration.
This is the list of paths that Glue (the autowirering-system from Cucumber) uses to find Classes to wire.
It seems like IntelliJ is generating this property, if it is not specifically defined in the the Template for "Cucumber Java"-Configs.

I don't know how it is generated, but for me the package that contains my class with the Before-Method in question did not exist. After adding it everything worked normally.

**Edit:**

Found out more background-info. The IntelliJ Cucumber Plugin does not use Junit oder TestNG, but his own implemented runner suite. This runner does NOT interepret the Annotation-Based configurations from Cucumber, only the ones from the Cucumber Property-File or System-Properties.
The TestNG-Suite however always overwrites the Glue-Path, not matter if it was actually set or is present.
The most consistent way I found was to configure it both using annotations and properties. That way you are always sure that you're config ist used (Gradle-Runner, TestNG-Runner, IntellijCucumber-Runner)

Comment: This helped me. I would also say than you can analyze with what parameters your tests run by copying this line (https://i.imgur.com/pKbhyns.png) and search for a "glue" word, then you will be able to identify what parameters intellij uses to run tests

Answer (score 1):

Check my test runner classs glueing the hooks in test runner has solved the issue i have defined hooks in this package "**com.memberweb.utilities**"

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = {"com/memberweb/stepDefinitions","com.memberweb.utilities"},
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.html",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json"
                },
        monochrome = true
)
public class testRunner {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case worked the addition of a package where @Before was defined to the glue parameter:

```
@CucumberOptions(glue = {"cucumber.hook", "cucumber.steps"})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it has worked when I put  "dryRun = false"  in the Cucumber options.