# JUnit runner class unable to execute @before

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber

below is the project structure:

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I6zt.png)

[Before After class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir8sR.png)

```
    Test Runner class:
    package runnerPackage;

    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(   plugin = {"html:target/cucumber-html-report",
    "json:target/cucumber.json",
    "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt",
    "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json"
     }, 
    features="classpath:MyFirstApp.feature",glue={"stepDefinitions"},tags=
    {"@sceneOne1"})
    public class TestRunner {

    }
Feature file :
@tag

Feature: Test HDFC

@sceneOne1

Scenario: Test HDFC

Given I open HDFC Bank home page and click on 'Login' button

***********************************************
Step Definition :

package stepDefinitions;

import pages.MyFirstMethod;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

public class MyFirstStepDefinition {


    MyFirstMethod m=new MyFirstMethod();

    @Given("^I open HDFC Bank home page and click on 'Login' button$")

   public void iOpenHDFCBankHomePageAndClickOnLoginButton() throws 

    Throwable {

    m.clickOnElement();

    }
 }
**********************************************
Before After class:

package runnerPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import pages.ConfigReadFile;

import pages.PageInstances;

import cucumber.api.Scenario;

import cucumber.api.java.After;

import cucumber.api.java.Before;
```

public class BeforeAfter extends PageInstances{

```
@Before
public static void runBefore(Scenario scenario)
    {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver_win32_2.26\\chromedriver.exe");
    System.out.println("reached here");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
    System.out.println(ConfigReadFile.URL);
    driver.get(ConfigReadFile.URL);

    }
    @After
    public static void runAfter()
    {
    System.out.println("do noting");
    }

}
**********************************************************
Page Instances:
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class PageInstances {
    protected static WebDriver driver;

}
```

Method:
package pages;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class MyFirstMethod extends PageInstances{

```
public void clickOnElement()
{
    Actions action=new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cee_closeBtn']/img[@alt='Close']"))).click();
    action.perform();
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cee_closeBtn']/img[@alt='Close']")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginsubmit")).click();
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    //loginButton.click();
```

}
}

```
Configuration xml:
<ConfigurationFile.xml>

<url>some random url</url>

</ConfigurationFile.xml>
```

Configuration Read File :

```
package pages;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class ConfigReadFile {

public static final String URL;

static {


File f=new File("file path");

DocumentBuilderFactory 

docbuildFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder builder = null;

try {
builder = docbuildFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e1.printStackTrace();

}
Document doc = null;
try {
 doc = builder.parse(f);
 } catch(Exception es)
{

}
URL=doc.getElementsByTagName("url").item(0).getTextContent();

System.out.println(URL);
}
}
```

**I want to open chrome browser and hdfc link for each secnario so I have annotated it with @before**

Comment: Do not post a link to a code's screenshot... Please enter the code here

Comment: Just by looking at the pictures. You don't have any tests to run, do you? Does the before and after methods really execute then?

Comment: @user7985169 change your question, do not post the code as comment

Comment: I'm not able to run a test class if an `@Before` annotated method is static or has parameters.

Comment: sorry I am unable to post code it's showing error

Comment: @user7985169 copy and paste your code from your IDE. Make sure inserting an empty line before your code and 4 whitespaces before each line of code

Comment: I have added the code let me know if anything more is needed

Comment: You are running the class with Cucumber runner which will not run the @Before annotation code.

Comment: could u please let me know the modification I have to do

Comment: make sure you're importing `cucumber.annotation.Before` source :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029341/before-doesnt-execute-in-java-cucumber-step

Comment: I have imported @Before from cucumber.api.java.before,I didn't find cucumber.annotation.Before

Comment: hello anyone please look into the issue,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should mention glue={"stepDefinitions","runnerPackage"} so that it loads hooks class